# How to make a query where one column is greather than other of the same table

Tags: mysql

When I try to do this :

```
SELECT * FROM BORROW  WHERE YEAR(BORROW.BORROW_DATE) = 2011 HAVING BORROW.RETURN_DATE > 
 BORROW.DEAD_DATE OR IFNULL(BORROW.RETURN_DATE, NOW());
```

The result gives me `RETURN_DATE` greater or less than `DEAD_DATE` and I want to return the valors where `RETURN_DATE` is greater than `DEAD_DATE` and have the `NULL` value too if that it's not returned.

Thank you!

Comment: Having is designed to work with group by so you should not be using it here.

Comment: Adding your tables will help users to answers faster and accurately.

Comment: Hi, please compare as Date(BORROW.RETURN_DATE) > Date( BORROW.DEAD_DATE) and use AND instead of OR as per your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move the null test.

```
SELECT * 
FROM BORROW  
WHERE YEAR(BORROW.BORROW_DATE) = 2011 and
IFNULL(BORROW.RETURN_DATE, NOW()) >  BORROW.DEAD_DATE
;
```

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day.